# Testing polynomial definition (from natural numbers to integers)

Tags: dependent-type, formal-verification, lean

For my first formalization. I want to define polynomials in Lean. 
The first attempt is shown below:

```
def polynomial (f : ℕ  → ℤ  ) (p:  (∃m:ℕ , ∀ n : ℕ,  implies (n≥m) (f n = (0:ℤ )  ) )):= f
```

Now a want to test my definition using:

```
def test : ℕ → ℤ 
| 0 := (2:ℤ )
| 1 := (3:ℤ )
| 2 := (4:ℤ )
| _ := (0:ℤ )
```

But I am having trouble constructing the proof term:

```
 def prf : (∃m:ℕ , ∀ n : ℕ,  implies (n≥m ) (test n = (0:ℤ )  ) ):=
 exists.intro (3:ℕ ) (
 assume n : ℕ,
 nat.rec_on (n:ℕ) 
 ()
 ()
 )
```

Also feedback on the definition itself is welcome.

Comment: A `list` of coefficients might be an easier definition to work with

Comment: @SebastianUllrich I considered that, but what if you want to define an addition and multiplication, isn't that more difficult if you have two polynomials of different degrees?

Comment: @JensWagemaker lists will be a little bit easier, but we still need an assumption: if the list is not empty then the head element should not be `0`. Otherwise, we would have `0 * x + 1` and `1` are different polynomials. List works, assuming that the head of the list is the lower coefficients, i.e. `[a, b, c]` represents the polynomial `c * x^2 + b * x + a`. For `prf`: in this case you do not want to use recursion, but `match`. The 0, 1, and 2 cases, should work with the proof `dec_trivial`.

Comment: @Johannes thanks, I'll try to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation of `def polynomial` does not work. You *tag* your function to be a polynomial, but this can not be used from the logic itself. Especially, it doesn't allow us to set up type class instances for polynomials.

What we want is a subtype instead:

```
def polynomial (A : Type) [ring A] : Type :=
{p : ℕ -> A // ∃ m : ℕ, ∀ n ≥ m, p n = 0}
```

with this we can setup a instance

`instance {A : Type} [ring A] : polynomial A := ...`

Comment: What is the meaning of the '//'? Also I can't find what {...} means, are you declaring a structure here? Is it possible to do the same definition more verbose?

Comment: `{x : A // p x}` is the subtype of all elements `x` in `A` for which `p x` holds. The `//` is part of the `{_ : _ // _}` syntax.